# Go to next UITextField in different UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with x number of cells. In some cells there is x number `UITextFields`. I want the next-button on the keyboard to highlight the next textField. I got it working in the same cell but not when it's supposed to jump to a textField in a different cell. The first textField in each cell has tag 0 and the second tag 1 and so on. This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    // Fetch current cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview;

    // Tag for next textField
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;

    UITextField *nextTextField;

    for(UITextField *subview in cell.contentView.subviews){

        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){

            if(subview.tag == nextTag){

                nextTextField = subview;
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    if(nextTextField){

        // Go to next textField
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    } else{

        // IndexPath for current cellen
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [travellersTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        UITableViewCell *nextCell;

        // While a cell exist at indexPath
        while([travellersTableView numberOfSections] > indexPath.section+1){

            nextCell = [self tableView:travellersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section+1]];

            if(nextCell){

                for(UITextField *subview in nextCell.contentView.subviews){

                    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){

                        if(subview.tag == 0){

                            NSLog(@"%@", subview.placeholder);

                            nextTextField = subview;
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                }

                // Go to next textField or cell
                if(nextTextField){
                    [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder]; NSLog(@"Next!");
                    break;
                } else{
                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section+1];
                }

            }

        }

        if(!nextTextField){ [textField resignFirstResponder]; }

    }

    return NO;

}
```

The `NSLog`'s behave as expected. I have different placeholders in the textFields and the next one is echoed. Next! is also echoed so it's trying to `becomeFirstResponder`.

Comment: Is it possible to have the tags increase from the previous value as opposed to going back to zero?

Comment: Short answer - no. I use the tags in a way that I need them to start from 0.

Comment: But still, it seems to work the way I've done it. It finds the right textField but it doesn't highlight it for some reason.

Comment: Sometimes I played around with the return NO; part and changed it to YES. That sometimes worked for me!!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I didn't fetch `nextCell` from my tableView correctly. This is how it should look like:

```
nextCell = [travellersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Always start tags from at least 1. Tags equal to zero causes serious problems. An object with tag 0 is often not initialized. Start your tags from 1 and check again.

Comment: I still get the same behavior